# ManytoMany relation in Django?

Tags: django, many-to-many

I have two models

```
class Group(models.Model):
    ....
```

and

```
class User(models.Model):
...
group = models.ManyToManyField(
    Group)
```

Have ManyToMany relation.

What's the best way to prevent delete `Group` instance if there are some `Users` with this `Group`

my solution is :

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            list_ = []
            
            for user in User.objects.all():
                for group in user.group.all():
                    if group.name not in list_:
                        list_.append(group.name)
                    else:
                        continue
                       
            if Group.objects.get(pk=kwargs['pk']).name in list_:
                return Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
            else:
                return self.destroy(request, *args, **kwargs)
        except:
            raise ValueError("Error")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `Group` got at least one user with:

```
def delete(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    items, __ = Group.objects.filter(pk=selk.kwargs['pk'], user=None).delete()
    if items:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
    else:
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_405_METHOD_NOT_ALLOWED)
```

This will filter and only retrain `Group`s that are empty. If `n` is thus `0` then it will take the `else` case, and return a 405. In case `n` is greater than zero (in this specific case it will always be one), then it will remove that `Group` record and return a HTTP 200 response.

Comment: I like your solution. what is equal items and _ ?

Comment: @tarp20: it unpacks the 2-tuple in `items` (which takes the value of the first item of the 2-tuple) and `__`. `__` is used as "throw away variable", whereas `items` contains the number of items removed.